# Odoo integration with Microsoft Dynamics AX

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-10, dynamics-ax-2012

Anybody know how to integrate the Odoo with the Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.

The scenario is I need to push the data from the Odoo to the Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 while creating in Odoo 10.

Does it have any proper solution ?

Comment: @FH-Inway Question is edited.

Comment: Thanks for providing the version information. It is still unclear what data you want to push and based on that there are several options. Take a look at [Plan data import, export, and migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/plan-data-import-export-and-migration) and [Plan for integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/plan-for-integration).